# How to change the value of parameters in a class using Python's Pygame library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to write a space invaders like game. I originally wrote my code to only supply 1 invader to give me something to build off of. When I began adding more invaders, I decided to create a class in which I could have the invader lists loop over.

I have tried to change the x-coordinate of the invader in a method in my list, but am finding that it does not change the value, thus the invaders are left in place. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the class that I am working on:

```
import sys, pygame, random
from pygame.locals import *
import itertools
#from bullet import Invader

pygame.init()
screen_height = 600
screen_width = 1200
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
FPS = 200

score = 0

pygame.display.set_caption('Testing Pygame')
spaceship = pygame.image.load('spaceship copy.bmp')

spaceship_rect = spaceship.get_rect()
DISPLAYSURF_rect = DISPLAYSURF.get_rect()

FONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
text = FONT.render('Score ' + str(score), True, (180, 180, 180))
text_rect = text.get_rect()
text_rect.centerx = DISPLAYSURF_rect.centerx
text_rect.centery = DISPLAYSURF_rect.centery

invader_right_movement = False
invader_left_movement = True

class Invader():

    def __init__(self, invader, invader_x, invader_y):
        self.invader = invader
        self.rect = invader.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = invader_x
        self.rect.y = invader_y

    def move_invader(self, movement):
        #self.x = self.rect.x
        #self.y = self.rect.y
        #Move invader
        if invader_right_movement == True:
            self.rect.x += movement
        if invader_left_movement == True:
            self.rect.x -= movement
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.invader, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

invaders_x = [10, 90, 170, 250, 330, 410, 490, 570, 650, 730]
invaders_y = 40

invader_image = pygame.image.load('invader.bmp')
invaders = []
for x in invaders_x:
    invaders.append(Invader(invader_image,x,invaders_y)) 

invaders_rect = []
for invader, x in zip(invaders, invaders_x):
    invader.centerx = x
    invader.centery = invaders_y


spaceship_rect.centerx = DISPLAYSURF_rect.centerx
spaceship_rect.centery = DISPLAYSURF_rect.bottom - 40

move_right = False
move_left = False
move_rate = 5

bullet_firing = False

#Testing bullet firing
RED = (240, 0, 0)
x = spaceship_rect.centerx - 3
y = spaceship_rect.top
width = 6
height = 24
#bullet = pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (x, y, width, height))
#bullet.centerx = spaceship_rect.centerx - 3
#bullet.centery = spaceship_rect.top + height
#bullet_rect = pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (x, y, width, height))
bullets_fired = []
bullet_fired = False

while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill((0, 0, 0))
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(spaceship, spaceship_rect)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(text, text_rect)


    #get invader to move 1-8 pixels randomly to one side before turning back
    num_movements = random.randint(1, 8)

    for invader in invaders:
        invader.move_invader(num_movements)

    for invader in invaders:
        if invader.rect.centerx >= screen_width - 30:
            invader_left_movement = True
            invader_right_movement = False
        if invader.rect.centerx <= 0 + 30:
            invader_left_movement = False
            invader_right_movement = True


    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

    #movement of bullet

    for bullet in range(len(bullets_fired)-1,-1,-1): 
        for invader in invaders:
            if invader.rect.colliderect(bullets_fired[bullet]):
                score += 1
                invader_x = DISPLAYSURF_rect.centerx
                invader_x = DISPLAYSURF_rect.top + 40
                del bullets_fired[bullet]
                bullet_fired = False
            elif bullets_fired[bullet].y > 0:
                bullet_fired = True
                bullets_fired[bullet].y -=  14
                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,RED,bullets_fired[bullet])


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #Movement of player
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                move_right = True
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                move_left = True

            #Bullet firing
            elif event.key == K_SPACE:
                if bullet_fired == False:
                    rect = spaceship_rect
                    rect.x = spaceship_rect.centerx - 3
                    rect.y = spaceship_rect.top
                    bullets_fired.append(rect)

        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            #Movement of player
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                move_right = False
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                move_left = False

    text = FONT.render('Score ' + str(score), True, (180, 180, 180))

    if move_right == True and spaceship_rect.right <= screen_width:
        spaceship_rect.centerx += move_rate
    if move_left == True and spaceship_rect.left >= 0:
        spaceship_rect.centerx -= move_rate

    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Please show all the code needed. The class looks fine as it is.

Comment: Ok I posted it as an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the class every frame which puts back its values to the ones assigned in `__init__`. You should call the class once at the start and then call the methods every frame. Here is a [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) to learn more about classes.

To fix your code, do this:

```
while True:

    #do other stuff

    for invader in invaders:
        invader.move_invader()

    #do other stuff
```

and since all the invaders have the same image, you could have

```
invader_image = pygame.image.load('invader.bmp')
invaders = []
for x in invader_x:
    invaders.append(Invader(invader_image,x,40,1))
```

this should move each invader by 1 pixel every frame

---

to get the rect for the collision you can add a rect to the class

```
class Invader
    def __init__(self, invader, invader_x, invader_y, movement):
        self.rect = invader.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = invader_x
        self.rect.y = invader_y
        #rest of code

    def move_invader(self):
        #if moveing move x
        self.rect.x = x
        #rest of code
```

and for the collision

```
for bullet in range(len(bullets_fired)-1,-1,-1): 
    for invader in invaders:
        if invader.rect.colliderect(bullets_fired[bullet]):
            score += 1
            invader_x = DISPLAYSURF_rect.centerx
            invader_x = DISPLAYSURF_rect.top + 40
            del bullets_fired[bullet]
            invaders.remove(invader) #to get rid of the invader too
            bullet_fired = False
            break
       elif bullets_fired[bullet].y > 0:
            bullet_fired = True
            bullets_fired[bullet].y -=  14
            bullet_rect = pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (x, y, width, height))
```

for the collision, i looped backwards because if you delete the 2nd bullet in the list, the 3rd becomes the 2nd and the loop goes to the 3rd (which was the 4th) skipping a bullet. But if you go backwards, if you delete a bullet, the bullets you have already checked get moved and you can keep checking the next one.

---

for the bullet, you have bullet and bullet_rect which are the same thing and you have a list for bullets, personally, i would get rid of bullet_rect

```
bullet = pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,(x,y,w,y))
```

for

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,bullets_fired[bullet]
```

now for where you add bullets, when you press spacebar, instead of getting y, just get the rect

```
elif event.key == K_SPACE:
    if bullet_fired == False:
        rect = spaceship_rect.copy() # this makes the bullet the same size as the ship
        #you could also do rect = pygame.rect(0,0,0,0)
        rect.x = spaceship_rect.centerx - 3
        rect.y = spaceship_rect.top
        #rect.w = width
        #rect.h = height
        bullets_fired.append(rect)
```

and back in the collision loop, change y to bullets_fired[bullet].y

Comment: Should I change my class to a function?

Comment: @GalacticAvenger Personally, i would use a class, because otherwise you will need a lists to store the x and y coordinates, which way they're moving, moving speed etc. but with a class, it can store all of this information and have methods to draw, move etc. I think it makes it easier to code as you only have one list of all the invaders that have all of their information.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am trying to get the invaders to move in sync and am wondering how to create a variable in the class that keeps its value after each item is iterated. In other words, I am trying to make invader_right_movement and invader_left_movement the same for each invader, but allowing each invader to change its value for all.

Comment: [this explains it and shows you](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Comment: I am receiving this error from the bullet movement "line 123, in <module>
    if invader.rect.colliderect(bullets_fired[bullet]):
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object"

Comment: I am running into a new error stating that on line 111 the list index is out of range. I posted the most recent version of the code. If you could give it a look over and see where you think I went wrong, I would be extremely appreciative.

Comment: It seems to be that once the bullet hits an invader, it deletes the bullet from the list but still keeps checking if the deleted bullet collides with the other Invaders. Add a `break` after `bullet_fired = False`. So it breaks the Invader loop and continues with bullet loop. I edited my answer above with this too.

Comment: It's actually on line 110

Comment: @GalacticAvenger So it doesn't fix it?. is line 110 `for invader in invaders:`. that shouldnt give an error

Comment: sorry for the late response, with your help I resolved this error.